# Python HTTP server that supports chunked encoding?

Tags: python, http, chunked-encoding

I'm looking for a well-supported multithreaded Python HTTP server that supports chunked encoding replies.  (I.e. "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" on responses).  What's the best HTTP server base to start with for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twisted supports [chunked transfer encoding (API link)](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.http._ChunkedTransferEncoding.html) (see also the API doc for [HTTPChannel](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.http.HTTPChannel.html)). There are a number of production-grade projects using Twisted (for example, Apple uses it for the iCalendar server in Mac OS X Server), so it's quite well supported and very robust.

Comment: Thanks, I've heard of Twisted, but my first impression was that it was a bit heavyweight for my task.  I'm going to take a second look, since it looks like you can download and run just twisted.web without the rest of the stuff.

Comment: I understand your feeling... twisted has a big API, seems a bit cultish and has somewhat of a learning curve. It put me off initially, too, but sometimes I do find it's the right tool for the job :-)

Comment: Dead link. Could you summarize in the future the contents of your links when posting?

Comment: now i can only find [twisted.web.http.Request](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.http.Request.html#chunked) who is chunked, but not found chunked response.

Answer (score 2):

Twisted supports chunked transfer and it does so transparently. i.e., if your request handler does not specify a response length, twisted will automatically switch to chunked transfer and it will generate one chunk per call to Request.write.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a simple chunked server using Python's HTTPServer, by adding this to your serve function:

```py
    def _serve(self, res):
        response = next(res)

        content_type = 'application/json'

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', content_type)
        self.send_header('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
        self.end_headers()

        try:
            while True:
                # This line removed as suggested by @SergeyNudnov
                # r = response.encode('utf-8')
                l = len(response)
                self.wfile.write('{:X}\r\n{}\r\n'.format(l, response).encode('utf-8'))

                response = next(res)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

        self.wfile.write('0\r\n\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
```

I would not recommend it for production use.

Comment: This line should be removed: `r = response.encode('utf-8')`. You don't need double encoding there. See my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72468791/9921853) to this question

Comment: @SergeyNudnov look at it now, I would suspect that it wouldn't actually run with r pre-encoded, so I will correct it with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that WSGI compliant servers should support that. Essentially, WSGI applications return iterable chunks, which the webserver returns. I don't have first hand experience with this, but here is a [list of compliant servers](http://www.wsgi.org/wsgi/Servers).

I should think that it would be fairly easy to roll your own though, if WSGI servers dont meet what you are looking for, using the Python's builtin [CGIHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html). It is already multithreaded, so it would just be up to you to chunk the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using [Tornado](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8080, help="run on the given port", type=int)

@tornado.web.stream_request_body
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print()
    def data_received(self, chunk):
        self.write(chunk)

        logging.info(chunk)

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below is a full working example. It could be used as a CGI script to stream data under Apache or IIS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pythonw
import sys
import os
import time

# Minimal length of response to avoid its buffering by IIS+FastCGI
# This value was found by testing this script from a browser and
# ensuring that every event received separately and in full
response_padding = 284


def send_chunk(r):
    # Binary write into stdout
    os.write(1, "{:X}\r\n{}\r\n".format(len(r), r).encode('utf-8'))


class Unbuffered(object):
    """
    Stream wrapper to disable output buffering
    To be used in the CGI scripts
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/9921853
    """
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def write(self, data):
        self.stream.write(data)
        self.stream.flush()

    def writelines(self, lines):
        self.stream.writelines(lines)
        self.stream.flush()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr)


# Ensure stdout is unbuffered to avoid problems serving this CGI script on IIS
# Also web.config should have responseBufferLimit="0" applied to the CgiModule handler
sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
print(
    "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\n"
    "Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8\n"
)

# Fixing an issue, that IIS provides a wrong file descriptor for stdin, if no data passed to the POST request
sys.stdin = sys.stdin or open(os.devnull, 'r')

progress = 0

send_chunk(
    (
        "event: started\n"
        f"data: {progress}"
    ).ljust(response_padding) + "\n\n"
)

while progress < 5:
    time.sleep(2)
    progress += 1

    send_chunk(
        (
            "event: progress\n"
            f"data: {progress}"
        ).ljust(response_padding) + "\n\n"
    )

time.sleep(2)

send_chunk(
    (
        "event: completed\n"
        f"data: {progress+1}"
    ).ljust(response_padding) + "\n\n"
)

# To close stream
send_chunk('')

########################################################
# All Done
```